# Simplifying Difference Quotient

Tags: calculus

I was watching lecture 3 from MIT 1801 on single variable calculus, and I am having trouble understanding how the professor simplified the expression for the difference quotient.
The original expression for the difference quotient was:
$$ \frac{\sin(x + \Delta x) - \sin(x)}{\Delta x}$$

and I understand how he simplified it to:
$$ \frac{\sin(x)\cos(\Delta x) + \cos(x)\sin(\Delta x) - \sin(x)}{\Delta x}$$
I just can't understand the simplification from the above expression to this:
$$ \sin(x)\biggl  (\frac{\cos(\Delta x) - 1}{\Delta x}\biggr) + \cos(x)\biggl(\frac{\sin(\Delta x)}{\Delta x}\biggr)$$

Could someone explain the steps involved to get to this solution?
Thanks,

Comment: Factor a $\sin(x)$ out of the first and third terms in the numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
 \frac{\color{blue}{\sin(x)}\cos(\Delta x) + \cos(x)\sin(\Delta x) - \color{blue}{\sin(x)}}{\color{green}{\Delta x}} &=  \frac{\color{blue}{\sin(x)}\cos(\Delta x) - \color{blue}{\sin(x)}+ \cos(x)\sin(\Delta x) }{\color{green}{\Delta x}}\\
&=   \frac{\color{blue}{\sin(x)}(\cos(\Delta x) - 1)+ \cos(x)\sin(\Delta x) }{\color{green}{\Delta x}} \\
&=\frac{\color{blue}{\sin(x)}(\cos(\Delta x) - 1)}{\color{green}{\Delta x}}+ \frac{\cos(x)\sin(\Delta x) }{\color{green}{\Delta x}} \\
&=\color{blue}{\sin(x)}\biggl  (\frac{\cos(\Delta x) - 1}{\color{green}{\Delta x}}\biggr) + \cos(x)\biggl(\frac{\sin(\Delta x)}{\color{green}{\Delta x}}\biggr)
\end{align}